# How to diagnose slow php image proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, nginx

I have an image proxy on my site that serves images on https from my domain to allow the SSL connection to be fully trusted.

Take for example this link:

https://www.mylesgray.com/lastfm/85982517.png

This serves album artwork from last.fm's CDN which is on HTTP, through HTTPS on my domain.

It is however chronically slow and I can't figure out why, the page it's accessing is:

http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/85982517.png

As you can see the speed difference is huge, though I can't work out why my script is so slow, it is very simple in it's operation:

```
$args = $_GET['q'];
list($img) = explode("/", $args);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo file_get_contents('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/' . $img);
```

All it does is grab the image and re-serve it.

Are there any ways to debug at what stage in the whole stack (from web server through to php scripting) that is causing this to be so slow?

You can see the effect this has when you compare these two pages:

https://mylesgray.com

https://mylesgray.com/blog

The second employing the proxy to serve the images.

Comment: Foregoing possible throttling at the CDN site (a lot of requests from 1 IP), why do choose to use PHP for proxying? `nginx` has a proxy module?

Comment: I'd start by logging `microtime()` before/after the `file_get_contents()`. I suspect you're going to see that they're throttling you.

Comment: Seems to be what it is - "Did nothing in 10.225450992584 seconds" between start and end of the get request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your webserver as problems to access the CDN, either they're throttling you, or maybe you have DNS resolution problems on your webserver.

So your webserver has to wait for the timeout of some DNS request to make another DNS request to another server to get the answer... which is taking a long time.

Good luck for your project.